# Runtime Error in C program on Online Judge (Problem ID: UVA482), seeking assistance

Tags: c, runtime-error

I have written a simple C program to solve UVA482 on an Online Judge. The program runs successfully on local tests and other platforms; however, I encounter a Runtime Error on the Online Judge.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    
    char ch, permute[1001][101], ans[1001][101];
    int i, j, testcases, pos[101];

    scanf("%d", &testcases);

    while (testcases--) {
        
        ch = '\0';
        for (i = 0; ch != '\n'; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &pos[i]);
            ch = getchar();
        }
        
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            scanf("%s", permute[j]);
        }
          
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            strcpy(ans[pos[j] - 1], permute[j]);
        }
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            printf("%s\n", ans[j]);
        }
        if (testcases != 0) {
            printf("\n");
        }
        memset(permute, 0, sizeof(permute));
        memset(ans, 0, sizeof(ans));
        memset(pos, 0, sizeof(pos));

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me identify the issue or suggest other potential causes for the Runtime Error? Thank you!

I encountered a Runtime Error on the Online Judge (Problem ID: UVA482). I tested locally, used memset for memory reset, and ensured compiler compatibility. Expected successful execution but still facing issues. Can anyone help identify the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There could be a buffer underflow at this line:

`strcpy(ans[pos[j] - 1], permute[j]);`

if `pos[j] == 0`, you will be accessing `ans[-1]`, which is off course undefined behaviour.

This is what i did to test your code:

- Saved your code as judge.c
- Compiled the code using gcc and google's Address sanitizer, using the command  `gcc -o judge judge.c -fsanitize=address -g3`
- Run the program with some random input.

I immediately got this runtime error from asan:

```
==2333519==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffd20ca3f6b at pc 0x7fd597a544bf bp 0x7ffd20c8b1a0 sp 0x7ffd20c8a948
WRITE of size 3 at 0x7ffd20ca3f6b thread T0
12    #0 0x7fd597a544be in __interceptor_strcpy ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_interceptors.cpp:440
    #1 0x557ed09605b1 in main /home/al/projects/stackovreflow/judge.c:25
    #2 0x7fd597629d8f in __libc_start_call_main ../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h:58
    #3 0x7fd597629e3f in __libc_start_main_impl ../csu/libc-start.c:392
    #4 0x557ed09601e4 in _start (/home/al/projects/stackovreflow/judge+0x11e4)

Address 0x7ffd20ca3f6b is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 101803 in frame
    #0 0x557ed09602b8 in main /home/al/projects/stackovreflow/judge.c:5

  This frame has 4 object(s):
    [48, 52) 'testcases' (line 8)
    [64, 468) 'pos' (line 8)
    [544, 101645) 'permute' (line 7)
    [101904, 203005) 'ans' (line 7) <== Memory access at offset 101803 underflows this variable
```

You can learn more about ASAN and how to use it to find runtime errors here [https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~learn/debugging/modules/asan/](https://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Elearn/debugging/modules/asan/)